# how does numpy reshape work with negative variable as second parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to play with negative variable as second parameter

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
print(np.reshape(a, (3,-1)) )
print("___________________________________")
print(np.reshape(a, (3,-2)) )
print("___________________________________")
print(np.reshape(a, (3,-3)) )
print("___________________________________")
print(np.reshape(a, (3,2)) )
```

All the four types of reshaping above basically gives the same result as the output.

> ```
> [[1 2]  
>    [3 4]  
>    [5 6]]
> ___________________________________
> [[1 2]  
>    [3 4] 
>    [5 6]]
> ___________________________________ 
> [[1 2]  
>    [3 4]  
>    [5 6]]
> ___________________________________ 
> [[1 2]  
>    [3 4]  
>    [5 6]]
> ```

I am just trying to understand what is the difference between the above? Can -1 and 2 be used interchangeably?

Comment: The `-1` just means, `calculate the required shape`.  Since reshape cannot change the total number of elements, if you specify all but one dimension, there is only one possible value for the remaining one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters to `reshape` can contain one unknown dimension which represented by a negative number, the value is inferred from the length of the array and remaining dimensions.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape

for example

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3, 4], [5,6,7,8]])
print(np.reshape(a, (-2)) )
print("___________________________________")
print(np.reshape(a, (2, 2,-2)) )
print("___________________________________")
print(np.reshape(a, (2, -1,-2)) )
```

Output

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
___________________________________
[[[1 2]
  [3 4]]

 [[5 6]
  [7 8]]]
___________________________________
...
ValueError: can only specify one unknown dimension
```

Answer (score 1):

Reshaping with a negative number is no magic. As stated in the answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57780169/7330813) the number after the negative sign does not really matter.

Here is a function demonstrating how reshaping is done. Note that this is purely demonstrative, not an actual implementation taken from source code or anything like that.

```py
def computeNegativeDim(arr):
    givenDims = list(arr.shape)
    knownDims = [d for d in givenDims if d > 0]
    val = 1
    for k in knownDims:
        val *= k
    dimOfPreviouslyUnknown = arr.size / val
    for g in givenDims:
        if g < 0:
            g = dimOfPreviouslyUnknown
    newarr = arr.reshape(givenDims)
```

Or somewhere along the above.

Comment: I don't get this.

Comment: @Pyromonk There was a mistake in the assignment of `g`. It should be more comprehensible now